# Azure Data Factory Having Two Azure Sql Sink and Load data in Alternate fashion

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-appservice

I have two Azure Sql sinks which has to be loaded from On Premise Sql DB , both are loaded in alternate fashion and switched over by App service once load is successful .
I am looking for various approaches to support two sinks and build my pipeline in such a way so that it can load data in alternate fashion and identify which sink to use .  Do we think we have to use two data pipeline or single pipeline can do both (by having some if /else , have  a flag in the database etc. ) ?
Looking forward for more inputs on this .

Thanks
Xsl Guy

Comment: Can you add some details on the "alternate fashion"? Data Flow can write to multiple sinks, so you could branch the data stream accordingly and have each one target a database.

Comment: We want to load data from On premise and ensure that user db is updated with latest data , to accomplish it we are planning to have two Azure sql database which will mirror each other but at any point of time one will be active while other will be passive , once data is loaded to passive then passive will be active , In the next load passive will loaded with the data and will be active. How we can ensure using ADF that we can maintain two sinks and load them one at a time . We also have to ensure only passive database is loaded with the data not active one.

Comment: @xslguy is there any way to know which Sql is in active and passive ?

Comment: Yes , this is just something which we have to decide , at any point of time only one will be active and Azure app service will be pulling data from it . I am thinking to maintain a flag (in a persistent storage ) to tell which one is active , however I am looking for more inputs if there are better way of achieving it in ADF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new table in both Sql DB (Sink SQL1 & SQL2) which is for maintain flag (here after coping the source to sink we can update the updated time)

[image]

Create a Stored Procedure on both Sink SQL1 & SQL2 and it will be call through lookup activity.

[image]

Create Linked services for both Sink SQL1 & SQL2 source and sink sql1 & sql2.

[image]

Create Dataset for source and sink SQL1 & SQL2.

[image]

Create pipeline Add two lookup activity SQL1 & SQL2 this lookup activity get **lastupdatedtime** from the sink sql1 & sql2.

[image]

Add If condition activity in pipeline and connect SQL2 and SQL2 in If condition activity. Select Activity tab and add Expression dynamically -> select logical function -> greaterthanorequal. In Add dynamic content shows **“@greaterOrEquals()”** after add Activity Outputs -> Lookup_activity_sql1 in ().  Then the Add dynamic container shows  **“@greaterOrEquals(activity(‘Lookup_activity_sql1’).output)”** here after output you can add the Lookup activity output value has “lastupdatetime”. **“activity(‘Lookup_activity_sql1’).output.lastupdatetime”**. like add SQL2 values in a Add Dynamic value as same as below screenshot.

[image]

Add a Copy activity & Stored Procedure Activity in If condition True & false Activity. Here the If Condition activity check the greater than value of Lookup sql1 & sql2. If it is True we will perform the copy activity and stored procedure activity for source and sink SQL1 in a True Activities. Else we will perform the copy and Stored procedure activity for source and Sink SQL2 in a False Activities.

[image]

In a Stored procedure activity we update the latest time in a Flag Table with respective Sink SQL1 & SQL2. You can add the below Stored Procedure in both Sink SQL1 & SQL2.

[image]

Some Additional way to achieve :

For example,

1. if the active/passive swaps on a schedule, then we could make an ADF trigger to match the schedule.
2. If there is some "hook" or "event" that happens when the active/passive swap, we could use  ADF to start pipeline run and name of correct sink. The SDK / API for ADF can be used to start pipeline.
3. If we used tumbling window trigger dependency, we could make the next data load, only if the previous data loaded. This would prevent one sink from getting beyond the other sink.

Comment: Thanks , I couldn't have asked for more , appreciate it for providing such thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's very hard to answer your question without a specific behavior. But since the source is on-premise SQL Server, you can't use Data Flow, it doesn't support self-hosted integration runtime. It means that you can't create one two sinks for one source.

Your purpose is copy data from on-premise SQL Server to tow Azure SQL database, you must create tow parallel copy actives with same source and different Azure SQL sinks like bellow:
[image]

Just according your logic, I'm afraid to say data factory can't achieve it. It more focus on data transferring and can't help you change the sink database status.

Comment: My thought process is copy to passive database only , so at one point of time it is only one database but in the next run it should be copied to other database(which becomes passive now) , however I am not sure how to support two sinks in alternate fashion , do you think maintain a flag in the database and then pipeline check for it will help , any thoughts please ?

Comment: @xslguy the key is how to identify the database? Data Factory can't do it. And no active can get the property of database.